# Return type of max{} in Ceylon

Tags: generics, type-inference, ceylon

I get why the inferred return type of [`max({})`](http://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.0.0/module-doc/index.html#max) is `Null` (and I think it's awesome how that function works with empty/possibly-empty/non-empty iterables), but why is using an empty named argument list—`max{}`—inferred to return `Nothing`? Why are those cases different? Is that intended?

This compiles and runs just fine,

```
Nothing foo = max{};
```

although I would've expected it to fail immediately if it actually evaluated `nothing`. Since `Nothing` is the subtype of everything, you can even do this,

```
Integer bar = max{};
```

and the compiler won't complain, but running that produces a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. What?! I thought we were never supposed to see that in Ceylon!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, nice one! It took me a few minutes thinking to understand what is going on here. So, as I guess you know, this:

```
max {}
```

Is supposed to be, in theory, the same thing as these:

```
max({})
max { values={}; }
```

Now, if you write either of those permutations, you will get the correct return type `Null` inferred for `max()`. And, indeed, if you execute either example, the result is, correctly, `null`.

Indeed, even if I run the following program:

```
void run() => print( max{} );
```

It prints `<null>`, as we would expect.

So what's going on here is that I have a bug in my type argument inference algorithm, where it fails to take into account the "implicit" empty iterable argument, a `{Nothing*}`, when inferring type args. Therefore, you're getting the inferred type `Nothing` for both type parameters of `max()`, because the type parameters are treated as unconstrained. Then, since `Nothing` is a subtype of `Integer`, the typechecker lets you assign the result to `Integer`. Of course the null value that is *actually returned* by the function is not assignable to `Integer`, so you get an NPE that of course should never happen.

The solution is I need to fix the bug. It will be a tiny one liner.

If you don't mind, would you submit a bug report to ceylon-spec please, and I will fix it tomorrow.

Thanks!

Comment: Bug report submitted.

Comment: I fixed the bug. Cheers.